# remove numeric characters from start of URLs in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

can any one explain how can i redirect /47-mycat1/subcat1-1/13articleid-articlename.html to /mycat1/subcat1-1/13articleid-articlename.html 
and 
redirect /17-mycat3/subcat3-2/97articleid-articlename.html to /mycat3/subcat3-2/97articleid-articlename.html?
in fact i want to remove "**47-**" in first url and "**17-**" in second url.

my all urls are something like http://www.mysite.com/**SOMENUMBSER-**.............

i use RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)-$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R] to remove "**SOMENUMBSER-**", but it doesn't work :(

please help.

Comment: i install [Multicategories Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/multi-categorization/12374) on joomla 2.5 and i can't view my featured contents in front page.
most type of [my site](http://www.barvarionline.com/) menu is Multicategories » Category Blog or Multicategories » Category List. i think may be i can fix my problem with redirect my featured contents to my menu content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+-(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

The second line of the code catches the url after the number and redirect to the url without the number.

Comment: ur code didn't work for me. please check : [myhtaccess.txt](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/myhtaccess.txt)

Comment: Try to move it to the third line of your htaccess.

Comment: I [changed .htaccess](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/myhtaccess1.txt) but my site getting 500 internal server error, so i undo the change. my current : [.htaccess](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/myhtaccess.txt).

i want to redirect my urls like http://www.barvarionline.com/42-infertility/treatment/146-new-methods-of-infertility-treatment.html to http://www.barvarionline.com/infertility/treatment/146-new-methods-of-infertility-treatment.html

Comment: But it's not my code. Try to replace `[R=301, L]` with `[R=301]` on the third line.

Comment: note: i changed .htaccess [view:myhtaccess2.txt](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/myhtaccess1.txt) and i replaced [R=301, L] with [R=301] ... my site is ok now but the link didn't redirect yet http://www.barvarionline.com/42-infertility/treatment/146-new-methods-of-infertility-treatment.html.
the url must be redirected to http://www.barvarionline.com/infertility/treatment/146-new-methods-of-infertility-treatment.html

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a temporary solution !
i turned off user url rewriting and add below code at the end of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/[0-9]+-(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

[view seo setting image](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/joomla-seo.png)

[view .htaccess file](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/17760719/myhtaccess2.txt)

my site www.barvarionline.com is now ok

thank you Lucas Willems for ur help :)

Comment: i uninstalled multicategorise component and now i use k2 in joomla.